# nginx entire site case insensitive without redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, apache-2.4

I have several WordPress sites that I've inherited managing.  On this one particular site, running nginx, (and CloudFlare if that matters) you can use any case on pages after the URL.  For example, www.example.com/TeSt will load the page www.example.com/test AND it will not redirect/change the case in the browser.  The page loads and the URL in the browser remains www.example.com/TeSt.  You can do this for any URL, /test, /media, /whatever and there are no specific rules in the site's nginx config for these directories/URLs.  First, I can't find any way to make nginx case insensitive site-wide and second, I only have experience using mod_speling in Apache which does a redirect, which they don't want.

Anyone have experience with this on nginx or Apache?  They have this one that works this way and want them all to be the same way.

Comment: My guess, nginx has nothing to do with it. It’s somewhere in wordpress site.

Comment: please provide your Nginx config